# Flickering light when ceiling fan is switched off

Tags: ceiling, light

I replaced a one way light switch that worked fine, with a nicer looking switch but now the ceiling fan light flickers when the switch is OFF. I installed a bulb flicker adaptor but it does not help. I will check the bulbs and the ceiling light connections next but I think its odd that the light flickers when it is off.

Comment: Edit your question with type of light/s.  When replacing the switch did you use the screws or back stabs(if any)?  Imagine the replacement switch was just a nicer looking face, not a different type(a funny smart or three way)?

Comment: The light is a standard (not led) globe, the ceiling fan is quite old. (i bought the house recently). The switch is a 1-way which I wired exactly the same way the old switch was wired